# Filter row based data on multiple criterias

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following row based dataset in pandas and want to filter modules that fulfill multiple critera, e.g. all modules with `(setting='Foo' and value=2) and (setting='bar' and value=1)`

Currently i am getting seperatly the modules for each criteria and then building the intersection of all single results. Is there a more efficient way, e.g. to transfer the dataset into a column based dataset and then filtering with one query `(setting_foo=2 and settting_bar=3)`

```
module    setting   value
-----------------------------------------
A         Foo       2
A         bar       1
B         Foo       3
B         bar       1
...
```

Desired output for this example would be module A because module B fulfills bar=1 but not foo=2

Comment: `df[df[['setting', 'value']].eq(['Foo', 2]).all(axis=1) | df[['setting', 'value']].eq(['bar', 1).all(axis=1)]`


https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to make columns for Foo and Bar for each module, as below:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='module', columns='setting', values='value').reset_index()
```

Gives:

```
setting module  Foo  bar
0            A    2    1
1            B    3    1
```

Then you can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter where Foo=2 and bar=1, and filter on the module column, as below:

```
df_pivot.loc[(df_pivot['Foo'] == 2) & (df_pivot['bar'] == 1), 'module']
```

Which outputs:

```
0    A
Name: module, dtype: object
```